# Laplace transform of $\sqrt{f(t)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a question about the Laplace transform.

Suppose the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is known. Is there any relation between the Laplace of transform $f(t)$ and that of $\sqrt{f(t)}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No obvious relations exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2(t) = f(t)$$

$$x(t) = \sqrt{f(t)}$$

$$x(t)×x(t)= f(t)$$

Multiplication in time domain gets converted into Convolution in s- domain

$$X(s)*X(s) = F(s)$$

X(s) is the laplace transform of $$\sqrt{f(t)}$$